# CheckBox в колонках ListBox не работает корректно. Как исправить?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, checkbox

Есть ListView с GridView. В нем колонка содержит CheckBox. 
Это задается стилем вида:

```
<GridView x:Key="SamplesGridViewTemplate">
    <GridView.Columns>
        <!-- Колонка с галочками -->
        <GridViewColumn  CellTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxColumnTemplate}"/>            
    </GridView.Columns>
</GridView>

<DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxColumnTemplate">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                              AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}" IsThreeState="False" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Проблемы:

1. CheckBox-ы появляющийся в отведенной для них колонке ListView не срабатывает с одного клика левым щелчком мыши. Требуется для этого 2 клика (двойное нажатие)
2. CheckBox-ы не работают если кликать мышью по строке в ListView (в любом ее месте), а хотелось бы именно такого поведения.
3. Не получается их выключать (снимать галочки) после того, как они там установились, тоже с первого раза.

В идеале требуется смена состояния Checked/UnChecked при одиночном клике по строке и (или) по самому CheckBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите, чтобы `CheckBox`'ы в строках `GridView` соответствовали выделению в `ListView`, то `Binding` должен быть двусторонним: `Mode=TwoWay`.

Например:

```
<Window x:Class="Equestria.ManeWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Mane 6" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Cool?" Width="45">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem},
                                   Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Pony"/>
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListViewItem Content="Apple Jack" IsSelected="True"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Fluttershy" IsSelected="True"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Pinkie Pie" IsSelected="True"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Rainbow Dash" IsSelected="True"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Rarity" IsSelected="True"/>
        <ListViewItem Content="Twilight Sparkle" IsSelected="True"/>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Если вам нужно отдельное состояние выделения, то байндинг к `IsSelected` ни разу не при чём, и надо сделать состояние по-настоящему отдельным. Например, вынести в attached property:

```
public partial class ManeWindow
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRadioSelectedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsRadioSelected", typeof(bool), typeof(ManeWindow));

    public static void SetIsRadioSelected (DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsRadioSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsRadioSelected (DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsRadioSelectedProperty);
    }

    public ManeWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Тогда останется сменить чекбоксы на радиобатоны с единым `GroupName` и добавить подсветку с помощью `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Window x:Class="Equestria.ManeWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:equestria="clr-namespace:Equestria"
    Title="Mane 6" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
  <ListView>
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
        <GridView.Columns>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Fav?" Width="45">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton
                    GroupName="Pony"
                    IsChecked="{Binding (equestria:ManeWindow.IsRadioSelected),
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
              </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
          </GridViewColumn>
          <GridViewColumn Header="Pony"/>
        </GridView.Columns>
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="equestria:ManeWindow.IsRadioSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListViewItem Content="Apple Jack" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Fluttershy"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Pinkie Pie"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Rainbow Dash"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Rarity"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="Twilight Sparkle" equestria:ManeWindow.IsRadioSelected="True"/>
  </ListView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Ваш вариант разметки у меня работает также, как и мой. Хотя, по логике, он более верный за счет включения  Mode=TwoWay. Теперь основная проблема- CheckBox не снимаются галочки при одиночных(да и двойные тоже не работают) нажатиях на строку в которой он уже включен. Как добиться отключения галочек при одиночных нажатиях на строку где они уже включены?

Comment: @DmitryB2014 У меня всё работает. Попробуйте запустить код в отдельном новом приложении. Возможно, в вашем приложении имеется какой-то код, который мешает правильной работе. Если проблема не в этом, то укажите ось и версию дотнета (хотя тут базовые вещи, вряд ли что-то поменялось).

Comment: Я постараюсь точнее описать поведение "галочек".В чистом проекте я вставил Вашу разметку, скомпилировал и запустил. В открывшемся окне щелкая по 1 разу в любой строке появляется "галочка". Если повторно щелкнуть в этой строке флажок не снимается. Для его снятия нужно щелкать другую строку.Однако он снимается и ставиться, если щелкать мышью с указателем мыши наведенным точно на сам "квадратик где флажок". Я пытаюсь получить поведение флажка описанное в предыдущем моем комментарии или самом вопросе.

Comment: @DmitryB2014 Вы хотите, чтобы обычный клик на строку работал как Ctrl+клик что ли? Для этого есть `ListView.SelectionMode=Multiple`.

Comment: Точно. Я хочу чтобы "галочки" ставились/снимались, как в режиме ListView.SelectionMode=Single и "Ctrl"+клик, но без необходимости удерживать дополнительно клавишу "Ctrl". Т.е мне нужно: 1. Одиночное выделение я его задаю ListView.SelectionMode=Single. 2. Поведение "Ctrl+клик" только с одним "щелчком" без клавиши "Ctrl".

Comment: @DmitryB2014 Ничего не понял. Поставьте Multiple и опишите чётко и по пунктам поведение во всех случаях, которое вас не удовлетворяет.

Comment: Поведение Multiple подходит("галочка" ставится/снимается одним кликом по строке), но: 1.Этот режим разрешает помечать несколько строк "галочками", что мне не подходит. Хочу разрешать помечать  "галочкой" только 1 строку одновременно причем одним кликом(как это работает в Multiple).

Comment: @DmitryB2014 В режиме Multiple подпишитесь на событие изменения выделения и, когда выделение меняется, сбрасывайте выделение со всех элементов, кроме последнего выделенного. Зачем вам чекбоксы — вообще не представляю, потому что они предполагают множественное выделение.

Comment: Я хочу "галочкой" визуально помечать строку, но оставить возможность выбирать другие строки списка без автоматического сброса установленной ранее галочки. Чтобы "галочка" снималась/ставилась только по команде пользователя, а не при каждой смене текущей выбранной строки в списке. И еще не допустить одновременное наличие более 1 помеченной "галочкой" строки в списке.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24777/discussion-between-dmitryb2014-and-discord).

Answer (score 1):

```
Нашел решение полностью отвечающее поведенческим требованиям поставленным в моем вопросе. Создаем в MainViewModel команду вида: 

//модель элемента списка ListView
public class Sample : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _ID;
    /// Уникальный номер.
    public int ID
    {
            get { return _ID; }
            set
            {
                _ID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
    }

    private bool _isChecked;
    /// Помечен или нет.
    public bool IsChecked
    {
            get { return _isChecked; }
            set
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
            }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<Sample> _Samples;
    /// Коллекция образцов
    public ObservableCollection<Sample> Samples
    {
       get { return _Samples; }
       set
       {
           _Samples = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("Samples");
       }
    }
    public ICommand PrepareSetCheckedCommand { get; set; } 
    //конструктор   
    public MainViewModel()
    {
       PrepareSetCheckedCommand = new 
       RelayCommand<Sample>(param=>PrepareSetCheckedElement(param), param => true);
    }   
     /// Подготовка к установке флажка на элементе строки ListView
     //<param name="param">Элемент для которого требуется установить/снять флажок.
     private void PrepareSetCheckedElement(object param) 
     {
        var clickedItem = param as Sample;
        if (clickedItem == null)
        {
              MessageBox.Show("ClickedItem is null!"); 
        }
        //сбрасываем флаги всех кроме кликнутого элемента 
        foreach (var itm in _Samples) 
        {
            if (itm.ID != clickedItem.ID) 
            {
                itm.IsChecked = false; 
            }
        } 
     }
}


//Разметка для частей ListView, такая:

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxColumnTemplate">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" IsThreeState="False" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},       Path=DataContext.PrepareSetCheckedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>

    <GridView x:Key="SamplesGridViewTemplate">
            <GridView.Columns>
                <!-- Колонка с галочками -->
                <GridViewColumn  CellTemplate="{StaticResource CheckBoxColumnTemplate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Header="IsChecked" />
                <GridViewColumn Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ID}" Header="ID" />
            </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>

        <!--  Стиль LV_CategoryStyle  -->
        <Style x:Key="LV_CategoryStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="True" />
        </Style>

        <ListView Name="LV_Samples"  View="{StaticResource SamplesGridViewTemplate}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding }"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource LV_Item}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=CurrentSample, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Style="{StaticResource LV_CategoryStyle}" >
        </ListView>
```

//Отдельная благодарность ув. Discord , который оказал большую помощь в его поиске